# Netlify does not load customed CSS when deploy Vuepress blog

Tags: deployment, netlify, vuepress

Hope you have a nice day.

I'm using a theme (vuepress-theme-gungnir) to make a little blog with Vuepress. Now I have finished personal edition to custom this theme.

Everything run perfectly at local (in dev mode, which I use npm run docs:dev), as well as after I run npm run docs:build, I also get a perfectly static files which is all custommed.

But after deploy to netlify, all my customs seems disappear. It only appear with original gungnir theme. The same thing happen with vercel. Other code in *.vue files also disappear.

I have been looking for many ways to figure it out, have tried many time to fix it, but there are very less information and it's not fixed at all. So I decide to ask you here with a hope.

You can clone my repo here https://github.com/DWSpace/dws-blog.git to run local to see the difference.

Deployd on Netlify: https://glowing-biscotti-276c40.netlify.app/

I am very appreciate your help.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

is it needed to deploy first and then upload static file with netlify OR we can you netlify to deploy?
Netlify's still deploy with raw code even I have not build static file first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).